# Merging two road layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, merge, line, road

I'm looking to merge two road layers. I am interested in the traffic volume in the second layer. The roads do not lay exactly on top of each other.

The issue is that sometimes when there is an intersection the road is taking the perpendicular value but I want it to take the parallel value. My first thought was to use a spatial join and join the closest join feature to the target feature with a 20 foot tolerance. I have also tried using the buffer tool then joining roads that are contained. But both methods are not producing the desired results.

An example photo is below. The buffered polyline is taking the value of the north and south road instead of the east and west road. I've also looked into Merge Divided Roads and snapping line to line but don't have the license for them.

[image: Intersection Example]

I have ArcGIS 10.5 and a basic license

Comment: Sounds like conflation ArcGIS pro has this toolset http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/an-overview-of-the-conflation-toolset.htm, it is unlikely you can do method without a higher license in ArcGIS (but possible with open source GIS and python tools)

Comment: Do you need to merge the geometries together?  If not then join the tables.  You could create efficient primary and secondary keys in the data based on road name and line direction.

Comment: Yes I need to merge the geometries. I unfortunately don't have any key to join them by so I need to use spatial relationships.

Comment: I actually found a pretty good solution that appears to work. I used a toolbox I found online to find the mid points of my target feature. I then took my new point target feature and joined it with the polyline join feature and used a closest (10 feet) spatial join. This appears to have remove gotten past the intersection issue. [link] (https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a2a41c8345e24ab6a9dd2ae215710b39)

Answer (score 2):

I actually found a pretty good solution that appears to work. I used a toolbox I found online to find the mid points of my target feature. I then took my new point target feature and joined it with the polyline join feature and used a closest (10 feet) spatial join. This appears to have gotten past the intersection issue. This appears to work since I don't have any points at the intersection.

arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a2a41c8345e24ab6a9dd2ae215710b‌​39

Edit: I am having some issues with overpasses but it appears to be specific to my data since only one side of the highway is annotated. The unannotated side of the highway can be miss-classified near overpasses. So if using this technique make sure to find the midpoints of the road with the most segmentation.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what you have done already, maybe you could try merging the vertical feature into the horizontal feature.  This should keep the attributes of the horizontal feature (feature being merged into). Use the same tool, but switch the order of operation.